# joomla printing page

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

anyone have a clue where to get a usable extension for Joomla.

I tried PrintMe but the extension is not downloadable....

Answer (score 0):

i got it sorted. PrintMe seems to be able to get it works as what I want...